# item is equal to any element in array

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql

I have a table from which some values are selected, which are being checked for existence in some other query later in the procedure. What is the right way of doing this?

Here is how I am doing it now:

```
table smt:

s_id | num
1    | 2
1    | 3
2    | 2

table smtable:

id | b_id
1  | 2
2  | 3
```

`arr_sid` should have: `{1,2}`

```
DECLARE arr_sid INT[];

SELECT s_id
    INTO arr_sid
    FROM smt
    GROUP BY s_id
    HAVING SUM(num) <> 0;

    SELECT id
    INTO val
    FROM smtable
    WHERE b_id = pid AND id = ANY(arr_sid);
```

I am getting this error:

```
ERROR: malformed array literal: "1"
SQL state: 22P02
Detail: Array value must start with "{" or dimension information.
```

Comment: You haven't shown enough code to reproduce the problem. Particularly, how is `arr_sid` defined?

Comment: I have made the necessary edits now..

Comment: Do you need the s_id's later on in the procedure?

Comment: No, I do not. It is just used to make the necessary existence check..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just have a select statement with a where clause and in that clause use the IN keyword and the second select statement:

```
SELECT id
INTO val
FROM smtable
WHERE b_id = pid AND id IN (
    SELECT s_id
    FROM smt
    GROUP BY s_id
    HAVING SUM(num) <> 0)
```

There is no need for the `arr_sid` variable, and further arrays are not standard SQL, whereas this query is portable.